# How to give animation effect onclick event on div segment?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am developing a widget for calculation of Freight.I have created two div. When we click on one div,it's display property sets to none and display property of another div is sets to block.I am facing the problem of setting animation or transition on second div like contact us and follow widgets on blogs.

```
<style>
#div1
{
    display : block;
    width : 150px;
    height : 50px; 
    background-color  : black;

}

#div2
{
    widht : 150px;
    height : 300px;
    display : none;

}
</style>

<body>


<div id = "div1">

</div>
<div id="div2">

</div>
</body>
```

click handlers

```
var div1=document.getElementById('div1');
var div2=document.getElementById('div2');

document.getElementById("div1").addEventListener("click",function(){


            if (div1 !== undefined && div2 !== undefined ) 
            {
                div1.style.display = div2.style.display === '' ? 'none' : div2.style.display === 'none' ? 'none' : 'block';

                div2.style.display = div1.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';

            }
        });
        document.getElementById("div2").addEventListener("click",function(){


            if (div1 !== undefined && div2 !== undefined) 
            {
                div2.style.display = div1.style.display === '' ? 'none' : div1.style.display === 'none' ? 'none' : 'block';
                                div1.style.display = div2.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';


            }

        });
```

and I have set an onclick event on both.So help me in setting animation or transition effect on div using onclick event.
If anybody has full widget code please share with me it will be very helpful to me.

Comment: Where are your click handlers ?

Comment: Please refer [how to create minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Edited the question with click handlers @Rayon

Comment: For transitions handled by CSS, usually you'd switch between two classes, one with the original layout, and another with the final animated effect using a CSS transition. JS would then add or remove the classes onClick.

Comment: Can you use css3 or jQuery?

Comment: yes we can use css3 and jquery but we need reference for doing this. If you have share with me or share some links reference study.@MoshFeu

Comment: Please share some reference. @Kyle

Comment: There is more than enough information in my comment to help you, good luck.

Comment: Okay I will explore it Thanks for your help @Kyle